# Source code doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, if I rightclick in any browser and choose to view source the code won't show up, even though i can clearly see the content on the page (tried on IE, Firefox, Chrome)

If I use the "inspect element" feature of Chrome/Firefox, I can however view the code

---

This is the respective code of my index.html:

```
            <!-- [TABLE] -->    
            <div id="centercol" align="center">
                <table id="table">

                </table>
            </div>
```

I'm using appendChild() to add the tr/td's in my javascript

InspectElement : https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2x5u.png

View Source : https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4lRN.png

---

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because if you're using Javascript to create HTML, that HTML isn't "source". You need to use a debugger.

Comment: +1 to offset downvotes. this question may be more basic than some but I don't see any reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewing source code sees the hard code / static code, inspecting DOM shows dynamic code as it's generated. You can get the generated source code using `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

The "source code" is the original response body sent from server. When you inspect element, it represents the live state of the page in serialized form.

For instance, literally just sending this from server:

```
<script>
```

Might become this in inspector as the above is parsed and serialized:

```
<html><head><script></script></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Not always true. I'm pretty sure different debuggers interpret things differently, and it also depends on the content-type. When inspecting a javascript file (literally plain javascript code, but has a content-type of "text/javascript"), it has the text inside of <pre></pre>, which is inside of <body>.

Comment: What specifically is not always true?

Comment: You just edited your post to disprove what I said. You claimed that sending "<script>" (always) becomes "<html><head><script></script></head><body></body></html>".

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't mean to imply that is always the case (I didn't even use the word always, I have now explicitly stated "might"), hence I clarified it :P

Answer (score 0):

The **source code** is the original document, unmodified by JavaScript

**Inspect element** shows you the serialization of the DOM, which is basically the markup that is visually represented on screen.

Comment: It shows serialization of the DOM, which cannot represent things such as `.value` or event listeners. DOM is not markup but in-memory object representation.

Comment: I wanted to give a very simple idea, for such a simple question. Didn't want to over-complicate it. However, I will steal the "serialization of" from your comment.

Comment: Since when can't you see ".value" in Firebug?

Comment: Since forever, the `value=""` attribute represents `.defaultValue` property. If you type something into a textbox, it will not show up as `value="the stuff you typed"` unless firebug does some dark magic for it which I hope it doesn't because it gives a false understanding of the value attribute.

Comment: @ianpgall you'd have to do this to see the value attribute update in firebug as you type into the input box: http://jsfiddle.net/KMw8H/1/

Comment: Hmm I don't know why, but I could've sworn that at least using Javascript, it was updated in Firebug. I knew that just typing in the textbox didn't change it though. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score -1):

It's happening because "viewsource" doesn't run JavaScript.
If your entire page is JS, then you'll just see the non-JS elements.